# How to handle sticky sessions issue?

Tags: c#, session, iis, webserver, load-balancing

I am running into this strange issue where few users of my app plug out their laptops from dock and move to WIFI network while using the application, Now after changing the network when they click on any navigation in the application it takes them back to the login page mentioning the session has expired.

Background: The server where the application is hosted have the load balancer which dynamically routes the incomming request, hence when user goes of from one network to another the old session maintained by the web browser stays open but load blancer identifies it as a fresh request and hence allocate to next available server which requires a login, now if user is fortunate to be routed on the same web server where he was before then all works fine otherwise he is redirected to new web browser.

Please help me resolving the rare scenario issue.
Thanks in advance.

Vishal

Comment: What is your load balancer? (e.g., is it Windows Network Load Balancer?)

Answer (score 0):

This issue depends mostly on your load balancer and the persistence of stickiness.

Some balancers handle the sticky persistence internally, so they have a table between client IP and route. Your case sounds like that.

Now, if you shift the persistence from the internal table to a cookie (or URL appendix), you can tackle the case. By using a cookie, the client will send the cookie on every request and the load balancer can check, whether the requested route is still valid and then serve the request. There is a non-IIS example for Apache (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html#stickyness_implementation), how they approach stickiness, but the feasibility depends on your balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have load balancing in-place then it is just a questions of whether to store the sessions in Jsession or Cookie, to avoid this issue I suggest your configuration the server to use Cookies. As by default Tomcat 7 (and I believe Tomcat 8) are configured to use Jsession